# 'I am going nowhere' or 'I am not going anywhere'

Tags: sentence

Is there any difference between these sentences?

- I am going nowhere.
- I am not going anywhere.

And are they correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentences are perfectly correct and mean technically the same thing but carry different overtones.

*I'm not going anywhere* is a simple statement of fact:-

> Will you still be here when I get back?
>
> Yes, I'm not going anywhere.

Whereas *I'm going nowhere* would be used when more emphasis is required; in an altercation in a shop, one would say

> I'm going nowhere until I get my money back

or when in a despondent mood:-

> My life is a wilderness of despair. I'm going nowhere.

Comment: It feels like "going nowhere" used more in spoken rather than in written form

Comment: And why did you think that ? It depends on the thematic expression the author wants to portray?i disagree with you....and what else do you want from "the answer" you looking for? Why don't accept his answer ? Click on tick mark..take a tour of the website..

Comment: Every construction in English (except the really archaic ones) is used more in spoken rather than written form. Words are spoken at a rate several magnitudes higher than the rate they are written. Think about it.

Comment: It can also be figurative, going somewhere without aim, to no particular place, or a place called *nowhere*; cp "he came out of nowhere", which certainly doesn't mean that he didn't come at all, quite the opposite. You might want to mention this in your answer. @argot: why so passive aggressive?

Comment: I think your wilderness example is more useful than the money back example.